# What is the fastest way to delete a already published publication?

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1

I have a publication which has multiple component and pages published.

I have a requirement to delete this publication. Is there any way I can delete this without un-publishing the component and pages?

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1.

Answer (score 7):

There are following two possible ways out there with 2013 SP1; you can analyze which suits you best:(Assuming you have remove any Blueprinting related dependency already)

1. Select the publication; `Right-Click -> Publishing -> UnPublish`. This will un-publish everything that was published from this publication to whatever targets you configured to use it.
2. you can decommission a publication target via the API (introduced in 2013 SP1). You can use TOM.NET API with the method `PublishEngine.DecommissionPublicationTarget` and the Core Service API with the method `DecommissionPublicationTarget`. This will let you delete a publication even in case there are any issues with the un-publishing.

Comment: Decomission was added as of 2013SP1, not 2013

Comment: Valuable information. updated the answer.